# Firefox <a download> issue

Tags: html, firefox, http-headers

`<a download>`, as I understand it, should download the response file on click.
I have the following code that doesn't work:

```
<a href="{{ download_url }}" style="cursor: pointer" download>Download PDF</a>
```

the relevant response header:

```
Content-Disposition: filename="Podsumowanie_wizyty_X_Y_2016-07-06.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2016 13:26:19 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.11
Vary: Authorization, Cookie
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
```

The returned file is viewed,  not downloaded.

I have also discovered, that the following example works well:
[example1](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download2)

But the following example views the file instead of downloading: [example2](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download)

Everything seems to work as intended in chrome.

Can something be done about it on my end? It should be able to work without `Content-Disposition: attachment;`. I would like to avoid tinkering with headers if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known and documented behavior.

In your case your HTTP header is not well-formed, `Content-Disposition` needs one between `inline` and `attachment` (actually it's slightly more complex, see [RFC1806](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1806) and [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)). `inline` is treated as default in FireFox (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).) but another browser may behave differently (regardless *priority* of `download` over `Content-Disposition`, see later.)

From this moment also browsers behavior diverges (and this explain the differences between the two other examples): Chrome gives the priority to `download` attribute while FireFox gives the priority to `Content-Disposition` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).)

Unfortunately you do not have any option but fix your HTTP header (if you want to support FireFox.)

Answer (score -2):

You have `download>` when it should be `download=`

Comment: See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download): *The attribute may have a value; the value, if any, specifies the default file name*. Note it says **may** not **must**.